# Swift Modular and testable Network Layer

Tags: swift, architecture

This question is more from the architectural point of view. Every time a new app comes along, there is a necessity to build a network layer of some sort, that encapsulates all the network logic from the other layers. My approach to this problem consists of having a **NetworkProtocol** whose job is declare every possible function available from the API.

```
protocol NetworkProtocol {  
    func getExample(completion: @escaping Result<Void> -> Void)
}
```

This protocol makes use of the **Result** type:

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(ErrorType)
}
```

After this I get a **NetworkClient** that requires a **NetworkProtocol** to be injected during it's initialization:

```
class NetworkClient {
   let client: NetworkProtocol

   init(client: NetworkProtocol) {
     self.client = client
   }
}
```

By doing this I can have a clear separation of concerns from the declaration of the Network layer and the implementation. It also let's me easily test the Network layer very easily by having a **NetworkClient** injected with a Mock Network.

My question here is if there is a better way of achieving all of this? One major problem with this solution is the fact that the **NetworkProtocol** easily becomes very big and a **NetworkManager** that implements this protocol.

Sorry if this is not the place for this question. Maybe it's more of a discussion then a question :)

Comment: The network stack is in the OS. I don't know what you mean by, "_Every time a new app comes along, there is a necessity to build a network stack of some sort._" I don't really believe you think you must create a new layer-2 (ethernet, Wi-Fi, etc.), layer-3 (IPv4, IPv6, etc.), layer-4 (UDP, TCP, etc.) for every application. The OS has that built into it.

Comment: The term NetworkStack refers to a layer of some sort that encapsulates all the Network calls and logic from the other layers. Perhaps network stack is not the most correct name :)

Comment: The term network stack refers to the code that implements the network layers. You can have an IPv4 network stack, an IPv6 network stack, an IPX network stack, etc. I think you are referring to the network APIs that let your applications use the network stack.